# How do I create a bean initialized my properties in my properties file?

Tags: spring, properties, constructor, applicationcontext

I'm using Spring 3.1.1.RELEASE.  In my application context, I'm trying to setup a bean with a constructor based on properties from a properties file. Here is my application context ...

```
    <!-- Define test properties  -->
    <util:properties id="applicationProperties" location="classpath:test.properties" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
            <property name="locations">
                    <list>
                            <value>classpath:test.properties</value>
                    </list>
            </property>
            <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="false"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="myprojectClient" class="org.mainco.subco.myproject.myprojectClient">
    <constructor-arg value="${quickbase.username}" />
    <constructor-arg value="${quickbase.password}" />
</bean>
```

and the top of my test.properties file …

```
# Quickbase credentials
quickbase.username=dalvarado-NONEMP@mainco.org
# It is expected that the password given here is encrypted.
quickbase.password=o37AbCdju57/nTWplI0oNg==
```

Here is how I declare the application context file in my JUnit test ...

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({ "classpath:test-context.xml" })
public class TrainingAssignmentDaoTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests {

…

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value="applicationProperties")
    private Properties m_testProps;
```

but I'm getting this exception, "Could not resolve placeholder 'quickbase.username'". What do I need to do to get my properties in there?

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:157)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:290)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'myprojectClient' defined in class path resource [test-context.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'quickbase.username'
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java: 209)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.processProperties(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:220)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:84)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:681)  
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:656)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:446)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:103)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:1)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(DelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:228)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:124)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:148)
        ... 24 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the *ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders* to true and try again.

```
<property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
```

You may have more than one org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer in your application (May be in you application context and test context).

Answer (score 0):

Since everything else is fine, it must be that your properties file is not on the classpath.
I assume you are running this from a unit test, try with this dummy test, assuming your context xml file name is `testContext.xml`:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:testContext.xml")
public class MyTest {

@Autowired
myprojectClient myprojectClient;

@Test
public void test()
{
    //use myProjectClient
}

}
```

This way you start the test with a Spring context that is initialized from the file which is specified in the `@ContextConfiguration`. It is possible to use multiple context files.
And one more thing, use capital letters for class names.

Comment: Hi, I agree there are some classpath problems, but I have this declaration (<util:properties id="applicationProperties" location="classpath:test.properties" />) in the spring context file (see my edit) and the autowiring of the properties file works just fine.  As for the JUnit configuration you suggest, I am doing exactly as you specified (also see my edit).

Comment: Well still I have no other idea than it's not on the classpath - I mean physically - where is it located exactly (in the file system), and what are you building with?